# scala: using method of extending class based on macros invokes trait default impl if type of instance is statically the base class

Tags: scala, scala-macros

I have a trait T,
I implement it with macro in class C.
i create an instance of C and invoke its methods.
if the type of the val containing an instance of C is C - works as expected.
if the type of the val containing an instance of C is T - invokes methods as if T.

best way to describe it that i can come up with is "virtual table broken" in scala-macros, but i don't know if that's a thing...

example code:

```scala
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala>

scala>

scala> import language.experimental.macros
import language.experimental.macros

scala>

scala>

scala> trait T { def doSomething(): Unit = println ("trait") }
defined trait T

scala>

scala>

scala> import scala.reflect.macros.Context
import scala.reflect.macros.Context

scala>

scala>

scala> object Macro {
     |   def doSomething(c: Context)(): c.universe.Tree = {
     |     import c.universe._
     |     q"""println ("macro")"""
     |   }
     | }
warning: there was one deprecation warning (since 2.11.0); for details, enable `:setting -deprecation' or `:replay -deprecation'
defined object Macro

scala>

scala>

scala> class C extends T { override def doSomething(): Unit = macro Macro.doSomething }
defined class C

scala>

scala> val c: C = new C()
c: C = C@3bd1883a

scala> c.doSomething()
macro

scala>

scala> val t: T = new C()
t: T = C@4079fec7

scala> t.doSomething()
trait
```

Comment: my actual use case is contributing a PR to scala-logging,
i want a base trait "ALogger" to be implemented by 2 different macro implementations,
and want consumers of the logger to be able to say abstractly that they have ALogger,
but for the logger to be determined later via Mixin or inheritance.
https://github.com/lightbend/scala-logging/pull/212

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Def macros are expanded at compile time so late binding / dynamic dispatch (which is a runtime feature) is impossible for them.

At compile time it's unknown that `t` has type `C`, at compile time it's only known that `t` has type `T`.

See details here:
Eugene Burmako. Unification of Compile-Time and Runtime Metaprogramming in Scala
https://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/226166/files/EPFL_TH7159.pdf
p. 98, §4.6.1 "Inheritance"

Comment: maybe it's a shame the macros are naive this way. maybe this could be somehow internally wrapped by a thin generated wrapper trait that behaves in a normal predictable way and has an implementation that is the expanded macro.
i don't know the implications this would have, but it's interesting.

Comment: @nathang Sorry, I don't understand how "thin generated wrapper trait" (whatever it means) can be helpful. At runtime `foo()` in `x.foo()` is selected based on runtime class of `x`. This information is not known at compile time yet. You can persist information from compile time for runtime (type tags, tasty, semanticdb). But in order to use runtime information at compile time you would need time machine. Or you would have to change standard workflow a lot: first compile time, first runtime (persist information), second compile time (use the information persisted), second runtime.